# Java class values getting overridden when calling constructor in a test case / different class

Tags: java, constructor

I have test case that does something like this

***TestSquare.java***

```
public void testEncaps() {
    Shifting shift = new Shifting(150,260);
    Square s = new Square(new Point(101,201),130,140,shift);    
    Point p = s.getMidPoint();
    p.x = 215;
    p.y = 315;
    assertEquals(new Point(101,201),s.getMidPoint());
}
```

So on the last line, the `s.getMidPoint()` don't equal to the `Point(101, 201)` but instead gets overridden with `215,315`. Here is my constructor code and get method.

***Square.java***

```
public Square(Point newP, int width, int height, Shift newS) {
    this.newMidPoint = newP;
    this.newWidth = width;
    this.newHeight = height;
    this.newShift= newS;
}
public Point getMidPoint() {
    return newMidPoint;
}
```

So, `s.getMidPoint()` shouldn't be replaced with the `Point` object. What am I doing wrong?

This two codes are in different class. So there is no main method in `Square.java`

Comment: If I follow your question, your issue is that you are modifying the instance of `Point` that you pulled from your `Square` by assigning to its coordinates. If you want to get the `midPoint` field safely, you need to perform some copying, not just pass out references to your object fields.

Comment: Yes, the issue is with ```Point``` changing the values of ```midPoint```. That said, how would I go about ```copying```. Can you please give some more hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want another class to be able to edit `Square`'s middle, return a new Point:

```
public Point getMidPoint() {
    return new Point(newMidPoint);
}
```

Then your test will run green.

Comment: ah brilliant. I didn't know that. Thank you so much.